# Alternative to $_SERVER['document_root'] as a relative argument

Tags: php, document-root

I'm using [PHP File Tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2007/06/php-file-tree/) to build a directory for a site, and I'm curious what alternatives I have to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to make the argument I'm passing through to a function become relative.

The page that calls the function is within the directory I am using the function on, so normally `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` would be perfect except my virtual host is using that directory as the root directory for a domain name.

So, for example, my server/hosting address is `http://s389593949.servername.com` but the domain `www.heresmysite.com` resolves to `http://s389593949.servername.com/HERESMYSITE/`, so the document root when used in the function returns `www.heresmysite.com/HERESMYSITE/therealfile.file` when it should be `www.heresmysite.com/therealfile.file`.

Is there something I can put in place of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to make it relative?  Something like `"/"` or `"../HERESMYSITE/"` so when the file name and link are appended they are correct to the relative path?  Those do not work.

(Yes, I am aware I can modify the PHP of the function itself, but I'm hoping to leave that untouched as I wish to use it in the future for other applications)

Many thanks, SO.

Comment: 1) `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not likely to be relative itself, it will probably give a full local file system path. 2) Are you trying to generate URLs or local file system paths?

Comment: What does $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] return?

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` doesn't work, unfortunately.  The function returns an error

Comment: and @DaveRandom, both.  Display the path, generate a link to it.

Comment: and @DaveRandom, sorry, read that wrong, I'm trying to generate URLs.  It appends whatever `scandir()` retrieves to the directory I provide it to search, though, so the URL ends up being incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

```
$docroot = str_replace('HERESMYSITE/', '', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
```

Comment: Not very dynamic though, is it? `I wish to use it in the future for other applications`

Comment: Well, that's not entirely true.  I can use this `$docroot` variable as an argument to pass it TO the function, but the function itself is what I intend on using multiple times, so it wouldn't really hurt anything.  Problem is, it appends the first argument (the document root), to the second argument (the file) when it generates a link, so it still comes out wrong.